# SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN showing last year data, why?

Tags: php, mysql

This query worked last year, but now this year it's showing last year's information. Why would that be?

```
$monday_date = 08-31-2015
$friday_date = 09-04-2015

SELECT * FROM cal_notes WHERE date BETWEEN '$monday_date' AND '$friday_date' ORDER by date ASC
```

Last year between 8-31 and 9-4 there were a few records and it showed those records. This year between those 2 dates it's showing records from this year between those 2 dates and also the records from last year between those 2 dates. How do I make it stop showing past years data?

UPDATE...

Here are all the different things i tried since i posted question and got answers. nothing seems to work. not getting any results any way i write it.

```
SELECT * FROM cal_notes WHERE STR_TO_DATE(cal_date, '%m-%d-%Y') BETWEEN '$monday_date' AND '$friday_date'

SELECT * FROM cal_notes WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`cal_date`, '%m-%d-%Y') BETWEEN '$monday_date' AND '$friday_date'

SELECT * FROM cal_notes WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`cal_date`, '%m-%d-%Y') BETWEEN '$monday_date' AND '$friday_date' ORDER by cal_date ASC

SELECT * FROM cal_notes WHERE STR_TO_DATE('cal_date', '%m-%d-%Y') BETWEEN '$monday_date' AND '$friday_date' ORDER by cal_date ASC

SELECT * FROM cal_notes WHERE STR_TO_DATE(cal_date, '%m-%d-%Y') BETWEEN '$monday_date' AND '$friday_date' ORDER by cal_date ASC

SELECT * FROM cal_notes WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m-%d-%Y') BETWEEN '$monday_date' AND '$friday_date' ORDER by date ASC

SELECT * FROM cal_notes WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d,%m,%Y') BETWEEN '$monday_date' AND '$friday_date' ORDER by date ASC

SELECT * FROM `cal_notes` WHERE `cal_date` BETWEEN concat(substr('$monday_date',7,4),'-',substr('$monday_date',1,2),'-',substr('$monday_date',4,2)) AND concat(substr('$friday_date',7,4),'-',substr('$friday_date',1,2),'-',substr('$friday_date',4,2))

SELECT * FROM `cal_notes` WHERE `date` BETWEEN concat(substr('$monday_date',7,4),'-',substr('$monday_date',1,2),'-',substr('$monday_date',4,2)) AND concat(substr('$friday_date',7,4),'-',substr('$friday_date',1,2),'-',substr('$friday_date',4,2))

SELECT * FROM cal_notes WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '$monday_date' AND '$friday_date' ORDER by date ASC

SELECT * FROM cal_notes WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%M %d,%Y') BETWEEN '$monday_date' AND '$friday_date' ORDER by date ASC

SELECT * FROM cal_notes WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`cal_date`, '%d,%m,%Y') BETWEEN '$monday_date' AND '$friday_date' ORDER by cal_date ASC

SELECT * FROM cal_notes WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`cal_date`, '%M %d,%Y') BETWEEN '$monday_date' AND '$friday_date' ORDER by cal_date ASC

SELECT * FROM cal_notes WHERE cal_date BETWEEN '$monday_date' AND '$friday_date' ORDER by cal_date ASC

SELECT * FROM cal_notes WHERE date BETWEEN '$monday_date' AND '$friday_date' ORDER by date ASC
```

Comment: Did you try by changing your date format to YYYY-mm-dd ?

Comment: `date` is a reserved word and if you use that as a table/column name, you have to put it in backticks. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html

Comment: i do sql query in navicat with YYYY-mm-dd and it doesn't work.

Comment: well maybe because i didn't change the values in the database to the new format, but i'm trying to avoid database changes to field types and data.

Comment: i changed the field name from date to cal_date and it still does the same thing.

Comment: What is the datatype of the `date` field. It makes a difference

Comment: varchar with format mm-dd-YYYY

Comment: Tah dah. That explains it

Comment: Convert the NOT A DATE `date` to a date before attempting the BETWEEN See @Uueerdo answer

Answer (score 2):

If the date format stored in the VARCHAR field is uniform you should probably be able to use [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date), like so:

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '[blahblah]') BETWEEN ....
```

Note that you are probably better off, though not much, converting the BETWEEN range bounds to properly formatted date strings of the YYYY-MM-DD configuration. (Such queries are going to be slow since they cannot take advantage of indexing).

Edit: In the case of this question `[blahblah]` should probably be `%m-%d-%Y`

Comment: what's the blahblah part for?

Comment: See the [Manual, its your friend](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: i guess date format, like %d,%m,%Y, but do i use format that is in database or convert to a different format that the script can use?

Comment: I suggest you use a logical date format and leave the USA format in the dust where it belongs. `STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2015-08-31' AND '2015-09-04'`

Comment: trying that and no data results are coming up

Comment: The format string should reflect the format used in the string, not the format you want. Note that it converts a string to a DATE type, where format. (see edit)

Comment: i understand, but i tried all sorts of things in there, with and without the square brackets and i'm getting no results.

Comment: No square brackets, those are just me enclosing "your stuff here". It should be `WHERE STR_TO_DATE(\`date\`, '%m-%d-%Y') BETWEEN ....` and if you haven't converted your $monday_date and $friday_date to 'YYYY-MM-DD' format, you'll need to call STR_TO_DATE() on those in a similar fashion.

Comment: it's still a no go, but i'm thinking, wouldn't the stuff after BETWEEN need that code too, or no? something like: "SELECT * FROM cal_notes WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`cal_date`, '%m-%d-%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$monday_date', '%m-%d-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('$friday_date', '%m-%d-%Y') ORDER by cal_date ASC"

Comment: That is what the comment above yours was indicating. Oh, also, I am not that familiar with PHP, but according to your supplied info, I think @monday_date is going to actually be something like -2038, not "08-31-2015"

Answer (score 0):

change the format of the fields to DATETIME

Comment: it's too big of a system to make that kind of a change now. need to be able to do it with a regular varchar string.

Comment: Again! This is not an answer to the question!?!?

Comment: @RiggsFolly , when there is sql query to access the data using the between command,then normally, the type of the fields should be DATETIME, to get the correct data.That's what is sujested.

Comment: Yes, I agree. BUT THAT WAS NOT THE QUESTION now was it. Thats quite a big change to make to a mature system, and nobody will do it on a whim

Comment: here the user is having an issue with getting correct data while using the between command, so i thought this can the solution,if he could implement.

Answer (score 0):

If the dates always follow the same pattern ( which seem a**e about face ) you could try the following - it's not pretty:

```
select * from `cal_notes` where `date`
between 
    concat(substr('$monday_date',7,4),'-',substr('$monday_date',1,2),'-',substr('$monday_date',4,2))
    and 
    concat(substr('$friday_date',7,4),'-',substr('$friday_date',1,2),'-',substr('$friday_date',4,2))
```

Alternatively, can you not rearrange the php variables prior to the query? I found that the `str_to_date` function failed with the date format of your variables....

Comment: doesn't seem to work. even ran the query straight on the database with hard-coded dates instead of variables and no results came up. i put in last year's year and this year's year and no results either way.